# expanding child to full width of parent inside overflow-x auto

Tags: css

How is it possible to stretch child div without setting fixed widths? Even if I try to wrap items and child in one wrapper div, the child div takes always 100%. Not full horizontal width. Thank you.

```css
.parent {
  background: skyblue;
  width: 350px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.child {
  background: springgreen;
  white-space: normal;
}

.item {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="item">
    This is some v y erty erty erty
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    This is serty erty erty erty erty
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    This is somerty erty erty erty ert
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    This .child div should extend horizontaly
  </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/45b0ypcq/2/

Comment: I think what you are looking for would be solved using flexbox, but still it is unclear what you want your output to look like. Could you share an image of what you expect?

Comment: @MariaNirmal HI, green div should extend to blue div width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.parent {
  background: skyblue;
  width: 350px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.parent div {
  flex: 0 33.333%;
}

.parent .child {
  background: springgreen;
  flex: 0 100%;
}

.item {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="item">
    This is some v y erty erty erty
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    This is serty erty erty erty erty
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    This is somerty erty erty erty ert
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    This .child div should extend horizontaly
  </div>

</div>
```

This is more flexible `CSS` [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) solution:

```css
.parent {
  background: skyblue;
  width: 350px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "item1 item2 item3"
    "child child child";
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: item1;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: item2;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: item3;
}

.child {
  background: springgreen;
  grid-area: child;
}

.item {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item item1">
    This is some v y erty erty erty
  </div>
  <div class="item item2">
    This is serty erty erty erty erty
  </div>
  <div class="item item3">
    This is somerty erty erty erty ert
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    This .child div should extend horizontaly
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: content of the main div should be overflown. not packed inside on one screen.